# Sizing a <td> from a string

Tags: php, html, database

I'm not sure if this is a HTML related issue or PHP, but:

I am loading a long string from a database into  tags. I want it to make it break into lines (instead if a giant line that spans past your screen size)when the string is loaded. How can i do this?

Comment: If you're targeting recent-ish browsers that are CSS3 aware, there is `word-wrap: break-word`, which will forcibly break/wrap long lines of text, even if there isn't a suitable break point in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `<p></p>` tag to contain the text you're trying to load and use CSS to constrain the size of it.

Also, I'd question the use of a table at all unless you're loading data that should be presented in a tabular format.

I'd also avoid making any formatting decisions on the PHP side unless you absolutely have to. Using PHP to auto-add `<br>` tags to everything, or using `<br>` tags to enforce page width is a really bad method. If they resize the browser window or change text height (accessibility) your forced formatting will get in the way.

TD tags get weird with content depending on the browser. If you can avoid using tables, I'd start there. If not, encasing the text in another block element, like `<p>` might keep it from stretching the `<td>` into one line, especially if you use a CSS style like `width: 100%` on the `<p>`. In general, PHP should do **no** formatting if you can help it, and HTML+CSS should do the rest. Tables are a bad choice when attempting to lay out a page, and should be replaced with `<div>` tags and appropriate CSS, with the only exception being data presented in tabular format, such as a table of data.

Comment: Formatting PHP-side is a fool's errand anyways. Getting client-side specs such as font size (and availability), window size, client size, etc... are unreliable and/or not universally supported. A 'fit' calculation that works on one browser/machine will be completely crazy on another.

Answer (score 0):

Combine PHP's `wordwrap()` and `nl2br()` functions to limit line size and then convert the newlines generated by `wordwrap()` into HTML `<br />`.

```
echo nl2br(wordwrap($alongstring, 72));
```

Not sure how this affects the `<td>` tags mentioned in your question title.  How are you using those?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a width to the container, it will wrap the text automatically when it reaches the end of the container unless you add `white-space:nowrap;` in CSS.